# net.thucydides.core.webdriver.DriverConfigurationError: Could not instantiate class org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity, serenity-platform

```
net.thucydides.core.webdriver.DriverConfigurationError: Could not instantiate class org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
    at net.thucydides.core.webdriver.WebDriverFacade.newDriverInstance(WebDriverFacade.java:181)
    at net.thucydides.core.webdriver.WebDriverFacade.newProxyDriver(WebDriverFacade.java:169)
    at net.thucydides.core.webdriver.WebDriverFacade.getProxiedDriver(WebDriverFacade.java:120)
    at net.thucydides.core.webdriver.WebDriverFacade.get(WebDriverFacade.java:209)
    at testCase.FirstTestCaseSerenity.dologin(FirstTestCaseSerenity.java:28)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at net.serenitybdd.junit.runners.SerenityStatement.evaluate(SerenityStatement.java:33)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at net.serenitybdd.junit.runners.SerenityRunner.performRunChild(SerenityRunner.java:445)
    at net.serenitybdd.junit.runners.SerenityRunner.runChild(SerenityRunner.java:419)
    at net.serenitybdd.junit.runners.SerenityRunner.runChild(SerenityRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at net.serenitybdd.junit.runners.SerenityRunner.run(SerenityRunner.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:756)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
Caused by: net.thucydides.core.webdriver.DriverConfigurationError: WebDriver was unable to create a new instance of type class org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
WebDriver reported the following message: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure. 
Host info: host: 'YUKON-QA1L', ip: '192.168.29.62'
Build info: version: '4.15.0', revision: '1d14b5521b'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.8'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [remote-allow-origins=*, --headless=chrome, --headless], extensions: []}}]}]
See below for more details.
    at net.thucydides.core.webdriver.WebDriverFactory.newWebdriverInstance(WebDriverFactory.java:152)
    at net.thucydides.core.webdriver.WebDriverFacade.newDriverInstance(WebDriverFacade.java:178)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure. 
Host info: host: 'YUKON-QA1L', ip: '192.168.29.62'
Build info: version: '4.15.0', revision: '1d14b5521b'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.8'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [remote-allow-origins=*, --headless=chrome, --headless], extensions: []}}]}]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:625)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:241)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.<init>(ChromiumDriver.java:108)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:89)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:84)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:73)
    at net.serenitybdd.core.webdriver.driverproviders.ChromeDriverProvider.newInstance(ChromeDriverProvider.java:73)
    at net.thucydides.core.webdriver.WebDriverFactory.createWebDriver(WebDriverFactory.java:164)
    at net.thucydides.core.webdriver.WebDriverFactory.newWebdriverInstance(WebDriverFactory.java:142)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void com.google.common.base.Throwables.throwIfUnchecked(java.lang.Throwable)'
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:192)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:Thechookie89
```

**Here is my code**:

```
@RunWith(SerenityRunner.class)
public class FirstTestCaseSerenity { 
@Managed WebDriver driver 
@Test public void dologin() { 
System.out.println("Debugging: Start of the test"); 
if (driver== null) {  
throw new IllegalStateException("WebDriver is null. Please check Serenity configuration.) } 
System.out.println("Debugging: Chromedriver path - " + System.getProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver"));
this.driver.get("https://google.com")}
}
```

Comment: I am new to serenity bdd framework my serenity.properties file :
serenity.project.name=VkAutomation Serenity Project
#webdriver.driver=chrome
webdriver.driver=chrome
headless.mode = true
webdriver.chrome.driver=src/test/resources/drivers/windows/chromedriver.exe

Comment: I m new to serenity bdd framework nd facing issues in my code

Comment: Can you share the code for reference? How are you instantiating your chrome driver?

Comment: @Techrookie89 I have added my code above please check

Comment: Can you also share the pom.xml/build.gradle dependencies that you've added to the project?

Looking at the stack trace its due to `Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void com.google.common.base.Throwables.throwIfUnchecked(java.lang.Throwable)'`